# How to set ui-tabs-tab hover style on none active tabs?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, tabs

I would like to use the jQuery UI Tab navigation with a custom style.
Therefore I need to know how I can set the ui-tabs-tab hover style as default style for all tabs that are not active.

```
.ui-tabs  {
    ....
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    ....
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-tab a {
    /* HERE I NEED to inherit the default jQuery Tab hover style */
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel  {
    ....
}
```

Comment: are you using jQuery UI tabs? https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Added it above. Yes, jQuery UI Tabs.

Comment: if I understand you correctly you need to set the same styles for .ui-state-default and .ui-state-hover

Comment: In jQuery tabs in hover of li `.ui-state-hover` class added.. so you need to css per that.. this the css code: `.ui-state-hover, .ui-tabs.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-tabs .ui-state-focus{}`

Comment: Yes, .ui-state-default shall become .ui-state-hover but only for ".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-tab a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your CSS file:

```
.ui-tabs-tab.ui-state-default a,
.ui-tabs-tab.ui-state-hover a {
    /*add your custom styles here*/
}
```